# How can I link together plugins and their configuration without knowing the type of either at design time?

Tags: c#, plugins, configuration, dependency-injection

Given a plugin that implements IPlugin:

```
interface IPlugin
    {
        void DoWork();
        void Configure(object config);
    }
```

The host application will load up the plugin, and then find its configuration class at run time and pass it to the plugin's `Configure` method.

How can I make `Configure` take a strongly-typed class instead of type `object`? Are generics the answer here? Marking up classes with attributes? The plugins will be loaded via MEF, in case that's a consideration. Please help me pose this question in a more objective way if this seems like polling.

Comment: Once the implementation plugin is loaded ; then find the type that implements this interface maybe through reflection and then invoke this methods

Comment: implements what interface? configuration will be different depending on the plugin. I already know how to load the plugin, I need a way of having an object unknown at design time to pass to the plugin to configure it

Comment: I recommend you to see the nopcommerce plugin architecture ...download the code and take a look at it https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/downloads/get/880002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on question and comments made it sounds like you are looking for this:

> Create a plugin that is unknown other than it implements `IPluglin`. Once found, create an unknown Configuration object and pass it in to get the plugin configured.

How would you know what type of Configuration object to create? You could get around the interface limitation of `object` and use a generic `TConfiguration`, but that doesn't really help because there is no way to know what the correct type the author wanted for their configuration.

I would actually follow [jaywayco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729082/jaywayco)'s advice and set up an `IConfiguration` interface with common members you need at the core.

The change I would make to this advice is adding an extra method to your interface called `CreateNewConfig` (or whatever you like) that returns you a new instance of the type of config the author wanted. No matter what it should implement the *new* configuration interface.

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    public IConfiguration CreateNewConfig();
    public void Configure(IConfiguration config);
}

void Test() 
{
    IPlugin myPlugin = PluginFactory.CreateSomePlugin();
    IConfiguration pluginConfig = myPlugin.CreateNewConfig();
    InitializeConfigWithCoreSettings(pluginConfig);
    myPlugin.Configure(pluginConfig);
}
```

The only other way to know exactly what config type the plugin wanted is to force them to declare the type in a property, but you can get that same information just by calling `CreateNewConfig().GetType()`.

There is a problem I see and that is you are allowing the plugin to configure itself. If this is the case, why are you needing to pass in an `object`? Surely the plugin can find a way to store its own configuration and read it. Unless you are serializing and deserializing the config the plugin used previously, I don't see the point in even needing to pass in a config other than for common properties you want them to have. If it really is core stuff, then definitely use an interface or your own concrete class.

Comment: The benefit to putting responsibility for plugin configuration in the host is to allow for a common UI for configuring all plugins.

Comment: @ChrisMcCall Then perhaps the best way is to slap a `Type` property on the `IPlugin` interface so the plugins can tell you what type they need for their config. I am assuming you have or are going to have something to dynamically build out the UI for the configuration and with that you only need to know the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and probably don't want to.

If you changed the signature of `Configure` to accept a strongly typed configuration object, you are limiting how other plugins can be configured.

Probably what you want, is another interface that provides a contract for the minimum configuration proprties that a plugin will need

So:

```
interface IPlugin
{
   void DoWork();
   void Configure(IConfigurationData config);
}
```

In my option makes more sense and your plugin, which has internal awareness of how it needs to be configured can attempt to cast `IConfigurationData` to something more verbose.

To satisfy the generics approach I would do something like this:

```
interface IPlugin
{
   void DoWork();
   void Configure<TConfig>(TConfig config) where TConfig : IConfigurationData;
}
```

The generics approach is probably syntactically nicer but they are essentially equivalent

Comment: of course I can, c# provides several means for using types unknown at design time, including generics and type attributes. Even a naming convention would be an option. If I gave up on the idea I would at least use an IDictionary. -1

Comment: No, you said "How can I make Configure take a strongly typed object instead of object" and you also say "configuration will be different depending on the plugin" so no, you cannot make configure accept different strongly typed object. Even if you used generics you would need to know something about the config object up front.

Comment: of course I can, that's what generics are for. I wouldn't have to know anything about the config object up front if I didn't want to. I am writing the host. The plugin would have to know what config object it was using to configure itself, then pass that in as the type parameter. Or use attributes. This is not a particularly novel problem.

Comment: I didn't ask "can I?" I asked "how?". The generics approach is syntactically equivalent to passing in a parameter of type Type to a property or constructor. Yet generics are used because they allow for type-checking at compile time for the user.